# Вызвано исключение по адресу нарушение прав доступа при записи по адресу. Программирование на С

Tags: c, ввод

Столкнулся с подобного рода проблемой. Пытаюсь скомпилировать следующий пример из учебника:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
printf("Type in your expression.\n");
scanf_s("%f %c %f", &value1, &operator, &value2);

if (operator=='+')
    printf("%.2f\n", value1 + value2);
else if (operator=='-')
    printf("%.2f\n", value1 - value2);
else if (operator =='*')
    printf("%.2f\n", value1 * value2);
else if (operator=='/')
    printf("%.2f\n", value1 / value2);

return 0;
```

Проблема следующая:
После ввода выражения в командную строку (например 4.5+3.2) вылезают вот такие ошибки. Возможно, вы сталкивались с подобного рода проблемами ранее и знаете как их решать?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Нужно сказать, что для ввода значений в учебнике используется scanf, а в моем случае VS19 банально отвергает scanf и насильно заставляет использовать scanf_s, что я собственно в течение всего процесса изучения.
Копался в описании этой функции и ошибок не увидел. Не судите строго за вопрос. Я только начинаю делать шаги в этом направлении=) Заранее спасибо за помощь.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уберите скриншоты и вставьте код и текст ошибок в тело вопроса.

Comment: Вопросы с просьбами помочь с отладкой («почему этот код не работает?») должны включать желаемое поведение, конкретную проблему или ошибку и минимальный код для её воспроизведения прямо в вопросе. Вопросы без явного описания проблемы бесполезны для остальных посетителей. См. [mre]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Неверно использована `scanf_s`. Может, в оригинале был вызов `scanf`? Так это разные функции...

Например, для `scanf` и чтения одного `char` достаточно

```
scanf("%c", &c);
```

а вот для `scanf_s` - на то она и безопасная :) - надо указать размер переменной:

```
scanf_s("%c", &c, 1);
```

Вот и получилась у вас ерунда...

Документация по `scanf_s` от MS - [тут](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/scanf-s-scanf-s-l-wscanf-s-wscanf-s-l?view=vs-2019).